# Translating an interpolation string statement

Tags: c#

Assuming

```
_tempPath = C:\Users\Temp 
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location = C:\Program Files\MySoftware
```

What would the output be of the following interpolated string statement?

`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{_tempPath}\" \"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location}\""`

I've done a bit of research but I am still unsure if these are two separate arguments passed to the process, or if they are combined into a single string.

Comment: Two arguments, assuming that's a space character between the quotes. Documentation is relatively easy to find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanx Heretic Monkey...  and I had already looked at the link you provided but apparently not close enough.  One last question... I'm guessing that the the two arguments are enclosed with quotation marks?

Comment: Why can't you print `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` and tell us what you see and ask any questions you have based on that output? More specifically, is `Arguments` field a string type? If so, then they are not "separate"

Comment: I KNOW what _tempPath is... What I'm looking for is the string created by: 
ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{_tempPath}\" \"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location}\""     And I'm using an older version of C# that DOESN'T have the"$" string interpolation function.

Comment: Then what version of C# do you have? We don't know this unless you tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output should be a single string - `"C:\Users\Temp" "C:\Program Files\MySoftware"`

Comment: Welcome back @AkshayBheda